# How does webRTC implement synchronization of the their audio and video streams from remote?

Tags: webrtc, stun

webRTC is implemented PeerConnection as per https://apprtc.appspot.com/

How does webRTC implement synchronization of the their audio and video streams from remote?

Comment: what do you mean with synchronization? do you mean the call or the streams sent to both parties?

Comment: That the audio and the video streams from remote are synced even though one may appear earlier or later with UDP. I see that the streams are sent via UDP on the console

Comment: If I really needed to know - and I'm not sure why I would - I'd go check the WebRTC project. It's open-source and available for inspection. See here: https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/checkout

Answer (score 0):

Normal RTP a/v sync done using RTCP SR/RR reports and the timestamps in each SRTP packet.

See any VoIP application.